# What is the difference between conn.execute('some string') and conn.execute(text('some string')) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What is the difference between `conn.execute('some string')` and `conn.execute(text('some string'))` in SQLAlchemy?

In the above, conn is obtained via `conn = engine.connect()`. And the engine is obtained via the `create_engine` method. The method `text()` is imported from sqlalchemy.sql`.

I see both `conn.execute('some string')` and `conn.execute(text('some string'))` occur in tutorials, but the difference is not explained. See for example [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-sqlalchemy/)

Kind regards

Comment: Note that bare strings as queries are no longer permitted in SQLAlchemy 2.0+: wrapping with `text()` is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is answered pretty well by the official documentation for [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text):

> The advantages `text()` provides over a plain string are backend-neutral support for bind parameters, per-statement execution options, as well as bind parameter and result-column typing behavior, allowing SQLAlchemy type constructs to play a role when executing a statement that is specified literally.

Of those the one you might use more commonly is the backend-neutral support for bind parameters. PEP 249 — DB-API 2.0 spec specifies a bunch of different [paramstyles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) an implementation can use. For example the `sqlite3` module uses qmark, while `psycopg2` uses format and pyformat. Using `text()` you can always just use the named style and SQLAlchemy will handle converting that to what your DB-API driver is using.

Another one you might run into is defining bind parameter behaviour when using an `IN` clause with a driver that does not support something like `psycopg2`s [tuples adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-tuple). Traditionally you would have to format the required number of placeholders to your query, but recent enough versions of SQLAlchemy support ["expanding" bind parameters](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.expanding) that remove the need for manual handling and allow treating a sequence as a single parameter.